# What is the proper way to catch and handle ORA-00001 SQLException with JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, primary-key, constraints, ora-00001

I'm creating a simple form that stores entered data in an extremely simple Oracle database table via a Java Servlet using JDBC.  That table is using the email address as a primary key.  If a user submits a form multiple times with the same email address, the `execute` function fails and throws a SQLException.  The exception's string is the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (...removed...) violated
```

In this scenario, I would like to catch this exception and deal with it by telling the user that the form cannot be submitted multiple times with the same email address.  What is the proper way to handle ORA-00001 separately and differently from any of the other SQLExceptions that can be thrown by `execute`?  A string compare could obviously work here, but that seems like a poor solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need to be DBMS independent use `SQLException.getErrorCode()`

It returns the vendor specific numeric error code. For ORA-0001 this would be `1`

Comment: actually, why 1 and not -1? compare: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS195

Comment: @ptrk: no idea, but the Oracle driver _will_ return `1` when you call `getErrorCode()`. You need to ask Oracle why they chose to use a negative value in PL/SQL but not in Java. (btw: your link is for the TimesTen database, which is something different than the "regular" Oracle database but that doesn't matter in this case)

Comment: I found it strange and can't google any explanation! Oracle seems to make a distiction between positive and negative on purpose, and yet it's ignore in Java. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm (plain Oracle PL/SQL this time ;) ) and note the NO_DATA_FOUND/ORA-01403 error with a value of +100.